# Protecting a pdf with a password using pdftk-php

Tags: php, pdf-generation, pdftk, php-pdftk

I have started using pdftk-php to populate form data into a pdf.  Everything is working great.  I would like to prompt the person viewing the newly created pdf (which is being viewed in the browser window) to add a password to protect the pdf prior to downloading/saving.
I have found the answer to adding passwords to pdfs using pdftk command line commands.  However, I do not understand how to execute it in php.  I found this line: 
pdftk sales_report.pdf output SalesReport.pdf user_pw PROMPT
in the page: https://www.linux.com/learn/manipulating-pdfs-pdf-toolkit.  Can anyone tell me how to modify the pdftk-php files to get this to work from within the php environment?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Simple answer.  In the pdftk-php.php file go to/around line 73 and locate the passthru() line.
Append the end of the line after "output -" to say "output - user_pw $password"
$password being the regular text password without the "$".
This doesn't prompt for creation of a password but does allow, through php, to create a variable on the page and use that as the password.  Worked for my needs.